# Height of a liquid in hemisphere that is part of in a horizontal cylinder

Tags: integration, geometry, definite-integrals, volume

How to calculate the height *h* reached by a liquid contained in a cylinder with a hemisphere at only one end?
I know that I have to calculate separately the volume of the cylinder and the hemisphere. The expression for the cylinder, in terms of the height *h*, I already obtained by calculating the cross-sectional area of the cylinder and then multiplying it by the length of the cylinder.
But I don't know how to calculate the cross-sectional area of this hemisphere, since I think it must be the same procedure as before, or similar.

The resulting expression for the volume of the cylinder was:

$$V = (R\frac{arcsin(h-R)}{R}+\frac{h-R}{R} \sqrt{R^2-(h-R)^2} +\frac{\pi}{2})L$$

where *R* is the radius of the cylinder, *h* is the height a liquid can reach and *L* is the length of the cylinder

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [here](/help/notation), [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: It is a half of a spherical cap: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_cap

Answer (score 0):

Let $0 \le k \le 1$, it's about calculating the volume:

$$
V(k) = 
\iiint\limits_{\Omega_1} 1\,\text{d}x\,\text{d}y\,\text{d}z + 
\iiint\limits_{\Omega_2} 1\,\text{d}x\,\text{d}y\,\text{d}z,
$$

$$
\begin{aligned}
& \Omega_1 = \left\{(x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R}^3 : x^2+y^2+z^2\le r^2, \, x \le 0, \, -r \le z \le (2\,k-1)\,r\right\}; \\
& \Omega_2 = \left\{(x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R}^3 : y^2+z^2\le r^2, \, 0 \le x \le L, \, -r \le z \le (2\,k-1)\,r\right\}. \\
\end{aligned}
$$

So, all that remains is to calculate:

$$
\iiint\limits_{\Omega_1} 1\,\text{d}x\,\text{d}y\,\text{d}z
= \int_{\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\frac{3\pi}{2}} \text{d}\theta \int_{-r}^{(2k-1)r} \text{d}z \int_0^{\sqrt{r^2-z^2}} \rho\,\text{d}\rho
= (3-2\,k)\,k^2\left(\frac{2}{3}\,\pi\,r^3\right);
$$

$$
\begin{aligned}
\iiint\limits_{\Omega_2} 1\,\text{d}x\,\text{d}y\,\text{d}z
& = \int_0^L \text{d}x \int_{-r}^{(2k-1)r} \text{d}z \int_{-\sqrt{r^2-z^2}}^{\sqrt{r^2-z^2}} \text{d}y \\
& = \frac{2(2\,k-1)\sqrt{k\,(1-k)}+\arccos(1-2\,k)}{\pi}\left(\pi\,r^2L\right);
\end{aligned}
$$

from which what is desired:

$$V(k) = \color{red}{(3-2\,k)\,k^2}\color{blue}{\left(\frac{2}{3}\,\pi\,r^3\right)} + \color{red}{\frac{2(2\,k-1)\sqrt{k\,(1-k)}+\arccos(1-2\,k)}{\pi}}\color{green}{\left(\pi\,r^2L\right)}.
$$